# How to pass variable/parameter as a datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to be able to change my datatypes and other values as a variable or as a parameter so that it could be changed and passed easily.

```
declare @datatype nvarchar(20) = 'datetime'
declare @inputvalue nvarchar(20) = '2015-10-21'
declare @variable @datatype = @inputvalue
exec spStoredProcedure @StoredProcedureParam = @variable
```

Comment: You can't do that. The data types are determined when the query is planned, so you can't change the data type depending on the data sent into the query. To create variables dynamically the query would need to create a query dynamically and execute it. This looks like an XY-problem, i.e. you should probably ask about what you are trying to accomplish, rather than asking about the solution that you think that it has.

Comment: There is [`sql_variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173829.aspx) type that may be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic sql inside your stored procedure for it, something like ....

```
declare @datatype nvarchar(20) = 'datetime'
declare @inputvalue nvarchar(20) = '2015-10-21'


    -- Inside your proc you would do something like.....

Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' Declare @variable '+ QUOTENAME(@datatype) + N' = @inputvalue '
         + N' Select @variable AS VariableValue'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                 ,N'@inputvalue nvarchar(20)'
                 ,@inputvalue
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact answer I'm looking for, not sure why I was even accused of asking an XY-problem.